# > Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin'] > For input string: ""

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I am currently getting a strange error running a gradle-script on one computer (the same worked there already and still works on another computer) Looks like some cache problem - but deleting .gradle did not help and I do not know how to delete the other one
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
➜  kontinuum git:(ligi_wip2) ✗ ./gradlew clean run --stacktrace
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.

* Where:
Build file '/home/ligi/kontinuum/build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'kontinuum'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin']
   > For input string: ""

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'kontinuum'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:176)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:181)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:599)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:125)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuildAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:233)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuildAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:230)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:160)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin']
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:155)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:112)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at build_59bsa4g28e7wfd7hj9y0560h5.run(/home/ligi/kontinuum/build.gradle:15)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
        ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.CacheVersion.getActualVersion(CacheVersion.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.CacheVersion.checkVersion(CacheVersion.kt:57)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.BuildCacheStorage.<init>(BuildCacheStorage.kt:83)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices.<init>(KotlinGradleBuildServices.kt:68)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices.<init>(KotlinGradleBuildServices.kt:34)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices$Companion.getInstance(KotlinGradleBuildServices.kt:54)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinBasePluginWrapper.apply(KotlinPluginWrapper.kt:41)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinBasePluginWrapper.apply(KotlinPluginWrapper.kt:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:139)
        ... 72 more
```

EDIT: 
 * rm -rf .gradle did not help
 * executing it with another user works fine.

Comment: Did you specify the version, as described in the reference?
 https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Comment: yes I did this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you post your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Because I did not see the reason to - this is the issue btw: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17125

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had this problem, and found that deleting the `build` folder and then rerunning the build fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try: 
1. Build -> Clean/Rebuild project
2. File -> Invalidate Caches
3. As Martin answered - remove **build** folder from root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

May not be applicable to your specific case, but I will just say for my part, I was seeing this same issue while I had my java home set to 1.7 in my CLI

Setting it back to 1.8 cleared it up lickity split. SDKMan having Java now is both super convenient but also covertly confusing if you're not careful lol